# Python - How to subclass typing.Union?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8, python-typing

I'm trying to subclass Union, not to change its behavior but just create a decorator that will check a specific type of Union.

So I've tried:

```py
from typing import Union

class MyUnion(Union[MyBaseDBClass, int]):
    pass

#or

class MyUnion(Union):
    pass

#...
# Below is the reason I can't use an alias, I want to reuse it in different scenarios
# I'm making a decorator that will automatically get the object in database 
# if an int(id) is given, but do nothing if the object is given as parameter
def user_is_admin(user: MyUnion[User, int]):
    #...
    pass
def project_is_active(project: MyUnion[Project, int]):
    #...
    pass
```

Both classes above give

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/typing.py", line 317, in __new__
raise TypeError(f"Cannot subclass {cls!r}")
TypeError: Cannot subclass <class 'typing._SpecialForm'>
```

So, how can I do it? I saw in the docs that you just need to add the specific protocols that Union has to your class, but I didn't find which protocols are these

Comment: Why do subclassing instead of `MyUnion = Union[str, int]`?

Comment: What do you think a subclass of `Union` or `Union[str, int]` would be? Type hints are essentially a superset of types; you can use any type as a type hint, but some type hints just aren't types. Subclassing applies to types, not type hints. (Further complicating matters, type hints are implemented as classes, but implemented in such a way to prevent you from doing class-like things with them, like subclassing them.)

Comment: Gave a bit more context as to why an alias wouldn't work

Comment: Oh wait, do I just need a class that implements .__getitem__? I think that flew over my head

Comment: I'm still not entirely clear on what you're asking, but if the question is how to make a "type-level" subclass that doesn't exist at runtime and only exists for correctness, then you may be looking for [NewType](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#newtype).